# AChartEngine, dynamic line plotting, crashing

Tags: android, dynamic, line, achartengine

I am a newbie in programming apps for android.
I am trying do plot realtime data with achartengine. The problem is that the application crashes, after the while.
The problem is the repaint-method and adding new data to the graph, should be Problems with the thread.
How can I control the thread, or find a better solution to draw the graph.
It would be great, if you could help me.

```
public class Plot2Activity extends Activity {

private static GraphicalView view;
private LineGraph line = new LineGraph();
private static Thread thread;
private static int x=0;
private static boolean mrepainted = false;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    view = line.getView(this);
    setContentView(view);     

    thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            /*for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Point p = MockData.getDataFromReceiver(x++); // new data
                line.addNewPoints(p); // add it to our graph
                view.repaint();
            }*/


            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Point p = MockData.getDataFromReceiver(x++); // new data
                line.addNewPoints(p); // add it to our graph
```

//                    Log.e("PLOT", "PLOT:"+x);
                    view.repaint();

```
            }

        }
    };
    thread.start();

}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //view = line.getView(this);
    //setContentView(view);        

}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```

}

LOGCAT:

> 10-08 13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-08 13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):
>   java.util.ConcurrentModificationException 10-08 13:23:22.012:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9267):   at
>   java.util.TreeMap$MapIterator.stepForward(TreeMap.java:883) 10-08
>   13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):     at
>   java.util.TreeMap$BoundedMap$BoundedIterator.stepForward(TreeMap.java:1485)
>   10-08 13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):   at
>   java.util.TreeMap$BoundedMap$BoundedEntrySet$1.next(TreeMap.java:1513)
>   10-08 13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):   at
>   java.util.TreeMap$BoundedMap$BoundedEntrySet$1.next(TreeMap.java:1511)
>   10-08 13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):   at
>   org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.draw(XYChart.java:250) 10-08
>   13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):     at
>   org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onDraw(GraphicalView.java:166) 10-08
>   13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):     at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:13458) 10-08 13:23:22.012:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9267):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13342)
>   10-08 13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929) 10-08
>   13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799) 10-08
>   13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):     at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340) 10-08 13:23:22.012:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9267):   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929) 10-08
>   13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799) 10-08
>   13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):     at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340) 10-08 13:23:22.012:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9267):   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929) 10-08
>   13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799) 10-08
>   13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):     at
>   android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461) 10-08 13:23:22.012:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9267):   at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467) 10-08
>   13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2183)
>   10-08 13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2256) 10-08
>   13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2151) 10-08
>   13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2019) 10-08
>   13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1830)
>   10-08 13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998) 10-08
>   13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
>   10-08 13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
>   10-08 13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):   at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555) 10-08
>   13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):     at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525) 10-08
>   13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):     at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
>   10-08 13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):   at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 10-08
>   13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 10-08
>   13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-08 13:23:22.012:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9267):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 10-08
>   13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-08
>   13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 10-08 13:23:22.012:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9267):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   10-08 13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 10-08
>   13:23:22.012: E/AndroidRuntime(9267):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)